# PCIe x1 connector

Tags: raspbian

May I ask whether the circled P & N pins are the original lines? I measured the original boards and lines, and my understanding should be
PCIE_TX_N --> PETN0
PCIE_TX_P --> PETP0

[image]
[image]
[image]